# Differences between in and on the market

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

"The monitors in the market" or "The monitors on the market". What is the right way? The software I use says "in" is wrong and it suggests "on".

To give context: I am talking about the computer monitors that I could find in the market.

Can someone explain the two options here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that is *in* the market exists physically within some actual location where they can be bought.

> I saw these same shirts **in/at the market** over on Front Street for half the price.

*On* the market is more of an idiomatic expression that simply indicates something is available for sale.

> These new dresses have been **on the market** for only two weeks, and most stores are already sold out.

Either can work for what you want to say.  If you saw the monitors within some specific, physical market then you would use *in* (or *at*).  If you are talking in general about the ability to buy the monitors, then *on* is more appropriate.

That being said:  In most contexts I wouldn't use either.  I would use the name of the place where they can be bought:

> You can buy these monitors from **Amazon**.
>
> **WalMart** has these monitors at a good price, if you want to get a couple.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I would agree that on is more correct</s> I guess this depends on what you want actually. If you were to use in, I would expect market to change to something like marketplace. Using in makes it seem like you are referencing a **place** where the monitors are at and not, say, arbitrary space like "wherever monitors are sold".